# mysql indexing makes group by slow

Tags: mysql

Please refer the table strcuture below.

```
  CREATE TABLE `oarc` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rtype` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1821039 ;
```

Other than the PRIMARY KEY, I have not set any index on this, and when I run the following query

```
select COUNT(oarc.ID) as total 
  from `oarc` where`oarc`.`rtype` = 'v' 
 group 
    by `oarc`.`zID`
```

I am getting the result in less than 1 second. But if I add index to zID it is taking more than 5 seconds.

Please see below explain result :

```
id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref      | row      | Extra
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | SIMPLE      | oarc  | index | NULL          | zone_ID | 4       | NULL     | 1909387  | Using where
```

Currently the table have more than 1821039 records in it and it will increase on a hourly basis.  What are the things I need to do in order to reduce the query execution time. I am expecting only something at the table and query level, nothing on my.cnf or server side because I can not do anything there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An index on rtype would appear to be more useful - but post the explain anyway.

Comment: Explain result added

Comment: The EXPLAIN refers to a column which is not present in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this better?

```
 CREATE TABLE `oarc` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rtype` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY(rtype,zid)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1821039 ;

explain
select COUNT(oarc.ID) as total 
  from `oarc` where`oarc`.`rtype` = 'v' 
 group 
    by `oarc`.`zID`

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | oarc  | ref  | rtype         | rtype | 3       | const |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: This is best.  Can you be please kind to explain me how this works.  Is the indexes are to be made in the order which is called in our sql query?  In this case rtype is used in where before zID in group by - am I correct?

Comment: Well, what happens if you reverse the order of the columns in the index?